# What is wrong with this coding? I get a error message method range of object worksheet failed

Tags: vba

```
Sub navrec()

Dim uut As Double
Dim defaultrange As Range
Dim colk As Range
Set colk = Range("k:k")
Set defaultrange = Range("a7:s50000")

Sheet4.Range(defaultrange).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="11", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="32"

With Sheet4.AutoFilter.Range


uut = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(colk.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
Sheet5.Range("c31") = uut
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: If `Range("a7:s50000")` is on Sheet4, just do `defaultrange.AutoFilter ...`, assuming Sheet4 is the active one.

Comment: Sheet4 is not the activeone

Comment: You can change `Const defaultrange As String = "a7:s50000"` and keep the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are messing up with range references a little

Here’s your code with a proper range handling (explanation in comments)

```
Sub navrec()

    Dim defaultrange As Range
    Dim colk As Range

    With Sheet4 ‘reference sheet 4 . From now and till next closing ‘End With’ statement all its members (like ranges) will be accessed by just premitting a dot
        Set defaultrange = .Range("a7:s50000" ‘ set referenced sheet range a7:s50000 as ‘defaultrange’ range . From now on every reference to ‘defaultrange’ will bring you to Sheet4 range a7:s50000
        Set colk = .Range("k:k") ‘ set referenced sheet column K as ‘colk’ range. From now on every reference to ‘colk’ will bring you to Sheet4 range k:k
    End With ‘ stop referencing sheet4

    defaultrange.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="11", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="32" ‘ filter ‘defaultrange’, i.e. Sheet4 range a7:s50000
    Sheet5.Range("c31") = =Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(colk.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)) ‘fill sheet5 C31 cell with the sum of Sheet4 range K:K filterd cells
End Sub
```

Comment: @Gowtham, any feedback?

Comment: Thanks Displayname. Helped me out.. Thanks for ur kindness

Comment: @Giwtham, you are welcome. And if my answer solved your question then you may consider marking it as accepted. Thank you

Comment: Accepted. Thanks DisplayName

Comment: @Gowtham, thumbs up!